# How to assert two JSON objects which have the same keys but different in values inside of a JSON array

Tags: java, json, automated-tests, testng, rest-assured

I have to assert two json objects which have the same key and they are included in a JSON array as below.

**Response value**

> [{"message":"Rest Endpoint should not be empty"},{"message":"Invalid URL"}]

But I am facing an issue when I am asserting the response, the objects do not receive as the way I am trying to assert as the order of the response objects are changing sometimes which leads to an assertion failure.

Below is the code which I am currently using to assert the objects.

```
Assert.assertEquals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("message").toString(), "Rest Endpoint should not be empty");

Assert.assertEquals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).get("message").toString(), "Invalid URL");
```

Sometimes what I received leads to an assertion error.

```
jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("message").toString() as "Invalid URL" and 
jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).get("message").toString() as "Rest Endpoint should not be empty"
```

**Full code Block**

```
//Requesting the resource API (save) with Payload
Response response = RestAssured.given().contentType("application/json").body(mydata).post("/api/v1/applications");
logger.info("/Save - Request sent to the API");

//Check valid Json responce
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().asString());
System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
Assert.assertEquals(jsonArray.length(), 2);
logger.info("/Save - Json Response validity pass");

//Check Response status code
Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 400);
logger.info("/Save - Responce code 400 OK");

//Check Response Objects received       
Assert.assertEquals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("message").toString(), "Rest Endpoint should not be empty");          
Assert.assertEquals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).get("message").toString(), "Invalid URL");
logger.info("/getAllApplications - Json Response received as :" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).get("message").toString());
logger.info("/getAllApplications - Json Response received as :" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).get("message").toString());
logger.info("/Save -3 API Testing Completed [Test 'RestEndPoint' field validation]");
```

Comment: [rest-assured]'s JsonPath used Groovy's GPath syntax http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath, this does not support inline sorting functions such as python's JsonPath extensions: https://gabbi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsonpath.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hasItem and `assertThat`, just convert `jsonArray` to `List`.

```
Assert.assertThat(Arrays.asList(exampleStringArray), hasItem("Rest Endpoint should not be empty"));
Assert.assertThat(Arrays.asList(exampleStringArray), hasItem("Invalid URL"));
```

where `hasItem` is part of `org.hamcrest.core`.

Comment: by using **hasItems** method the second line of assertion can be eliminated.

Answer (score 3):

**Found the Solution**

```
//Create a string list and iterate the Json array to fetch the required text with the same key 

List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>(jsonArray.length());

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            responseList.add((jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("message")));

}

//Assert the list
org.junit.Assert.assertThat(responseList, hasItems("Rest Endpoint should not be empty", "Invalid URL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven for your use case, I would include this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This should help you in the getting the objects compared without having to worry about the order.

Here is a [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) in how to use it as well.